# Compatibility in the text format between DOS and windows

Tags: windows, text, dos

I'm using the iperf tool which runs in DOS , so here is the command

Actual Command:::

```
    iperf -c IP address -w 8M -f m -t 1000 -i 10 -P 4 -y C
```

The output format for this is:

```
                 20120411124341,192.168.1.103,49179,192.168.1.102,5001,3,0.0-10.0,25952256,20761804
                 20120411124341,192.168.1.103,49181,192.168.1.102,5001,5,0.0-10.0,33816576,27053260
```

But when i try to output this format to a .txt file using the > symbol, it doesn't acknowledge the carriage return, it dumps everything in a single line, which similar to this.

```
    iperf -c IP address -w 8M -f m -t 1000 -i 10 -P 4 -y C > C:\test\a.txt
      20120411124341,192.168.1.103,49179,192.168.1.102,5001,3,0.0-10.0,25952256,2076180420120411124341,192.168.1.103,49181,192.168.1.102,5001,5,0.0-10.0,33816576,27053260
```

How Can i get the actual format when i try to store it in the .txt format. Is this is the issue with notepad??? Answers are appreciated.

Comment: You can use Wordpad to open the .txt file, it's a little more forgiving on line endings. P.S. the problem is most likely with iperf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iperf uses a character (line feed) for a line break, while windows based systems like notepad uses 2 characters (line feed, carriage return).
You should use a more powerful text editor (like Notepad++) where you can select the line break char(s) to display it properly.
Here you can see more info about line breaks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline